# Groupby in columns with condition to return different results?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the dataframe below:

```
     equipment      value      loc
0       ac1         43.2       acs_blg
1       ac2         23.1       acs_blg
2       ac3         0.0        acs_blg
3       ac4         44.4       acs_blg
4       kz1         12.1       qet_blg
5       kz2         87.2       qet_blg
6       kz3         65.3       qet_blg
7       yy1         0.0        cna_blg
8       yy2         0.0        cna_blg
9       yy3         0.0        cna_blg
10      yy4         0.0        cna_blg
11      yy5         0.0        cna_blg
12      uu1         55.3       ppp_blg
13      uu2         0.0        ppp_blg
14      ta1         24.3       lck_blg
15      ta2         22.0       lck_blg
16      ta3         21.0       lck_blg
```

I will want to return a string based on 3 conditions:

1. If all equipment in a loc has more than > 0.0 value, return 'Online'
2. If one or more equipment in a loc has 0.0 value, return 'Check'
3. If all equipment in a loc has 0.0 value, return 'Offline'

End result

```
     loc        status
0    acs_blg    Check
1    qet_blg    Online
2    cna_blg    Offline
3    ppp_blg    Check
4    lck_blg    Online
```

What is the best tackle approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare values by `0` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then use [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) and 
[`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test if all ar at least one match and last create new column by [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
mask = df['value'].eq(0)

df1 = mask.groupby(df['loc'], sort=False).agg(['any','all']).reset_index()

arr = np.select([df1['any'] & df1['all'], df1['any'], ~df1['any'] & ~df1['all']], 
                ['Offline','Check','Online'])

df2 = df1[['loc']].assign(status=arr)
print (df2)
       loc   status
0  acs_blg    Check
1  qet_blg   Online
2  cna_blg  Offline
3  ppp_blg    Check
4  lck_blg   Online
```

Another idea is sum columns and compare if equal `1`, `0` or `2`:

```
mask = df['value'].eq(0)

df1 = mask.groupby(df['loc'], sort=False).agg(['any','all']).reset_index()
print (df1)
       loc    any    all
0  acs_blg   True  False
1  qet_blg  False  False
2  cna_blg   True   True
3  ppp_blg   True  False
4  lck_blg  False  False

s = df1['any'].add(df1['all'].astype(int))
print (s)
0    1
1    0
2    2
3    1
4    0
dtype: int32

arr = np.select([s.eq(2), s.eq(1), s.eq(0)], ['Offline','Check','Online'])

df2 = df1[['loc']].assign(status=arr)
print (df2)
       loc   status
0  acs_blg    Check
1  qet_blg   Online
2  cna_blg  Offline
3  ppp_blg    Check
4  lck_blg   Online
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `loc` column, get the `value` column into respective lists, and apply `any` and `all` to get the conditions :

```
#groupby loc and aggregate the values column into a list
res = (df.groupby("loc").value.agg(list)
       .reset_index()
      )

#create conditions for the checks

#all entries are greater than 0
cond1 = [all(entry) for entry in res.value]

#at least one entry is greater than 0
cond2 = [any(entry) for entry in res.value]

#no entry is greater than 0
cond3 = [not all(entry) for entry in res.value]

condlist = [cond1, cond2, cond3]
checklist = ['Online','Check','Offline']

#apply the numpy select function
res['status'] = np.select(condlist,checklist)

#drop values column
#it has served its purpose
res = res.drop("value", axis = 1)

res


     loc    status
0   acs_blg Check
1   cna_blg Offline
2   lck_blg Online
3   ppp_blg Check
4   qet_blg Online
```